# Hermitian Matrices with At Most Pair-wise Eigenvalue Degeneracy

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $n\in2\mathbb{N}$ be given.

Let $H\in Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ be a Hermitian traceless matrix such that its eigenvalues have at most pairwise degeneracy. (That is, if the eigenvalues are $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^n$ then we *allow* that $\lambda_i = \lambda_{i+1} \forall i\in\{1,3,\dots,n-1\}$, but no other degeneracies other than that.)

*Conjecture*: The set of all such matrices $H$ is homotopy-type-equivalent to $S^m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Question: Is this conjecture true? If yes, how to prove it, if no, is there anything else this is homotopy-type-equivalent to?

Comment: It is certainly not homeomorphic under the usual topology.  In particular, $H$ fails to be compact, unlike $S^m$.  Maybe you can choose an appropriate subset of $S^m$, though.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thanks for your comment. I edited the text to change from homeomorphic to homotopy-type-equivalent. Perhaps now it makes more sense?

Comment: I really have no idea how to approach this. It may be worth noting that $H$ is dense in $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, the set $\mathcal H_n$ of such matrices is contractible for $n=2$. We can define a deformation retraction to a point by the formula $R(H,t)=tH$. Each matrix $tH$ is again Hermitian, traceless (as these two properties are preserved under multiplication by real numbers) and has at most pairwise degeneracy (this is vacuously true for $2\times 2$ matrices). This doesn't work for higher $n$, since the zero matrix is no longer an element of $\mathcal H_n$.

Comment: I guess $n=2$ is not in the category of interesting cases because (I suppose I forgot to mention this) there should also be at least a pair of eigenvalues which are non-degenerate. So in the $n=2$ case when you have a pair which is degenerate you don't have at least two separate eigenvalues. In the $n=4$ and so on cases this condition is automatically fulfilled by the already prescribed conditions.